# Performance issue with the index load in mvc5 kedno

Tags: performance, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, database-performance

i have the controller with the followinf code.
and

```
         public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["ContractNumber"] = Mapper.Map<IList<Contract>, IList<ContractModel.contract>>(contractService.GetAll()).AsQueryable();
            ViewData["ContractorName"] = Mapper.Map<IList<fContractor>, IList<ContractorModel.contractor>>(contractorService.GetAll()).AsQueryable();
            ViewData["ServiceNameString"] = Mapper.Map<IList<fServiceDetail>, IList<ModelServiceDetail>>(serviceDetailsService.GetAll()).AsQueryable();


            return View(ViewData);
        }
```

each table in the mapper has aroung 500 to 1500 records.

when executed, it takes a long time to return to the index.

can some one suggest the code that fixes the performance onlaod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is fixed.

issue is about mappers and resolver extensions.